# RSA, finding p,q

Tags: rsa, number-theory

If the public key $(e,n)$ and the private key $(d,n)$ are known, what is the easiest way to find the primes $p$ and $q$?

When $n$ and $\phi(n)$ are given this is easy to solve. But I can't manage it given just $(e,d,n)$.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: If you have $e$ and $d$, and you know that $ed \equiv 1 \pmod{\varphi(n)}$ - or $\mathrm{lcm}{(p - 1, q - 1)}$ - what can you deduce?

Comment: Maybe that p-1 and q-1 are divisors of ed-1? @Thomas

Comment: Correct, now how do you use this knowledge to find the factors of $p$ and $q$ efficiently? Hint: how many times can $2$ divide $p - 1$ or $q - 1$? What about $ed - 1$? With this you should be able to find an efficient way to produce a congruence of the form $a^m \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$ and $a^m \not \equiv 1 \pmod{q}$ and thus find $p$ (can you see why?)

Comment: @Thomas I think, probably I should use the Fermat's little theorem here. 2 divides p-1 ϕ(p-1) times,⋅q-1 ϕ(q-1) times, and ed-1  ϕ(p-1)*ϕ(q-1) times. Am I on the right way?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow what you mean by "2 divides p - 1  ϕ(p-1) times", but the basic idea is this: if 2 divides $p - 1$, $x$ times, and 2 divides $q - 1$, $y$ times, then 2 divides $ed - 1$ at least $\max(x, y)$ times. So if you keep dividing $ed - 1$ by 2, at some point you will end up with a number that is a multiple of $p - 1$ but not of $q - 1$ (or vice versa). Then using Fermat's little theorem can produce a factor of $n$ (there are some details but that is essentially the idea).

Comment: If you prefer, you can use the following idea: since $ed - 1$ is a multiple of both $p - 1$ and $q - 1$, if follows that $a^{\frac{ed - 1}{2^k}} \equiv \pm 1 \pmod{p, q}$ for some small $k$. Thus trying a bunch of random $a$'s, you will quickly find an $a$ which is a quadratic residue modulo $p$ but a quadratic nonresidue modulo $q$, such that $a^{\frac{ed - 1}{2^k}} - 1$ is a multiple of $p$ but not of $q$, and you are done.

Comment: see my question [Is knowing the private key of RSA equivalent to the factorization of N?](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/16036/is-knowing-the-private-key-of-rsa-equivalent-to-the-factorization-of-n)

Answer (score 2):

It's quite easy to find out the two primes $p$ and $q$ given the secret integer $d$ and the public modulus $n$ and the public exponent $e$.

An algorithm is found on the Appendix C of document [SP800-56B](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/nistpubs/800-56B/sp800-56B.pdf).

I copy it here:

Appendix C: Prime Factor Recovery (Normative)

The following algorithm recovers the prime factors of a modulus, given the public and private exponents. The algorithm is based on Fact 1 in [Twenty Years of Attacks on the RSA Cryptosystem, D. Boneh, Notices of the American Mathematical Society (AMS), 46(2), 203 – 213. 1999. ].

Function call: RecoverPrimeFactors(n,e,d)

Input:

1. n: modulus

2.e: public exponent

3.d: private exponent

Output:1.(p,q): prime factors of modulus

Errors: “prime factors not found”

Assumptions:
 The modulus $n$ is the product of two prime factors
$p$ and $q$; the public and private exponents satisfy $de ≡ 1 \, (\mod  \lambda(n))$ where $λ(n) = LCM(p– 1,q– 1)$

Process:

1. Let $k = de – 1$. If $k$ is odd, then go to Step 4.
2. Write $k$ as $k= 2^tr$, where $r$ is the largest odd integer dividing $k$, and $t ≥ 1$.
3. For $i=1 \dots 100$ do:

   a. Generate a random integer $g \in [0, n−1]$.

   b. Let $y = g^r \mod n$.

   c. If $y= 1$ or $y = n– 1$, then go to Step g.

   d. For $j \in [1, t– 1]$ do:

   ```
     I. Let $x = y^2 \mod n$.

     II. If $x = 1$, go to Step 5.

     III. If $x =n– 1$, go to Step g.

     IV. Let $y=x$.
   ```

   e. Let $x=y^2 \mod n$.

   f. If $x = 1$, go to Step 5.

   g. Continue.
4. Output “prime factors not found” and stop.
5. Let $p = \gcd(y– 1, n)$ and let $q = n / p$.
6. Output $(p,q)$ as the prime factors.

Comment: Before seeing your question, I was looking for the same algorithm and when I found the specification and wrote some python code to implement it and test. You'll find an improvable but working code here: https://gist.github.com/ddddavidee/b34c2b67757a54ce75cb

Comment: $e$ is not supposed to be secret. $\;$

Comment: yes, I agree, sorry I correct the answer. (thanks!)

Comment: You can skip step 1. $\lambda(n)$ is even, $ed$ has to be odd, and $ed-1$ has to be even again.

Comment: @ddddavidee check my comment in your gist. Also thanks for sharing, I solved a CTF (https://id0-rsa.pub/problem/45/) with your script :)