# RSA: Multiple Private keys for single public key and N

Tags: rsa

I'm working on a problem that gives me two private keys $d_1,d_2$ that work with the same $(N,e)$ pair. The problem gives me the two private keys and $N$. Is it possible to find $p$ and $q$? Or how would I find $p$ and $q$ or the sum $p+q$?

Comment: A single private key and the matching public key is enough to factor the public modulus $N$; see [this](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/16036/555). This is why it is a bad idea that several public keys share the same modulus $N$. Further, if several private keys match the same public key $(N,e)$, then these private keys are functionally equivalent (they need not be equal).

Comment: But the public key is not given

Comment: The question as stated makes no sense: for fixed $N$ and $e$ there is only one possible value of the private key $p$, $q$, and $d$ (up to equivalence modulo $\lambda(N) = \operatorname{lcm}(p - 1, q - 1)$).

Comment: @SqueamishOssifrage: "up to equivalence"; I suspect that's the trick that textbook is looking for...

Comment: But this problem has already been solved before, I'm just wondering how it was done.

Comment: I forget where the question was, but someone said that for RSA you only need a multiple of (p-1)(q-1)

Comment: Write down the relation between $d$ and $e$, and the problem practically solves itself…

Comment: I solved it. d2 - d1 = n+1-(p+q)