# Crack RSA with $e$ and $d$?

Tags: rsa, attack

Is it possible to decipher a ciphertext, in RSA with small primes (two 128-bit factors) when we only have ciphertext $c$, private exponent $d$ and public exponent $e=65537$ to crack it? I try hard on this question but I couldn't find $N$.

First try, I write the code to find factors of $ed-1$ and find it on factordb and try to find out $p$ and $q$ but it doesn't help at all

```
from itertools import chain, combinations

def powerset(iterable):
    s = list(iterable)
    return chain.from_iterable(combinations(s, r) for r in range(len(s)+1))

def another_set(all, subset):
    for s in subset:
        all.remove(s)
    return tuple(all)

from functools import reduce

factors = [2,2,13,17,17,137,263,397, 11119,99181,12203,12330780871,94976914459050383474573,663887747473781762461237]
all = powerset(factors)

for subset in all:
    p = subset
    q = another_set(factors.copy(), p)
    p = reduce((lambda x, y: x * y), p, 1)
    q = reduce((lambda x, y: x * y), q, 1)
    if isPrime(p+1) and isPrime(q+1):
        print(p+1,q+1)
```

Comment: Could you check if [this Q/A](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/78330/1172) has enough to resolve this for you? Is this part of a challenge / capture the flag?

Comment: @MaartenBodewes that Q/A assume that we have N but in this question there is no d, yes this is a part of CTF already finished. Unfortunately there is no write up for this question.

Comment: Duplicate of this [later question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/105747/555). There is now little doubt this is a thinly disguised CTF, homework or similar. No matter how interesting and fun, that's off-topic. [update] Ah it's [admitted](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/226368) it's a CTF, and we are told it's finished. [update] [Here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/105762/555) comes another duplicate. Perhaps we should not take "finished" at face value.

Comment: @fgrieu it was a ctf but it was finished and i was curious to solve it, the later question you mention link refrence to my question again!

Comment: To the OP: I modified the question to clarify the givens. Could you please check the current version, and [edit](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/posts/105734/edit) it to tell the bit size of the given $d$ as per [`d.bit_length()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#int.bit_length) ? From your code I think it's 255-bit (343…229, equivalently 0x4b…c5), but can't be sure.

Answer (score 2):

Since this is a CTF, I won't give quite a full solution, just try to unstuck the OP (who seemingly made significant progress).

We are given $e$ and $d$. They must match $e\,d\equiv1\pmod{\operatorname{lcm}(p-1,q-1)}$, but because the bit size of $d$ is just one bit below the sum of the bit sizes of $p$ and $q$, and because that's a common way to compute $d$, and also we can test that $e\,d\equiv1\pmod 4$, it's a reasonable betthat $d=e^{-1}\bmod((p-1)(q-1))$, and I'll assume that unless it's proven otherwise.

It follows that $e\,d-1=k\,(p-1)(q-1)$ for some integer $k$. Since $p$ and $q$ are large primes, they are odd, and we get the integer equation
$$\frac{ed-1}4=k\,u\,v\quad\mathsf{with}\quad u=\frac{p-1}2\quad \mathsf{and}\quad v=\frac{q-1}2$$
The question already lists the factors of $e\,d-1$, from which we extract the $12$ factors of $k\,u\,v$ :

```
13 17 17 137 263 397 11119 12203 99181 12330780871 94976914459050383474573 663887747473781762461237
```

We need to split these factors into the integers $k$, $u$ and $v$. Their respective base-2 logarithm, rounding to two decimals towards nearest, are the 12 values

```
3.70  4.09  4.09  7.10  8.04  8.63  13.44  13.57  16.60  33.52  76.33  79.14
```

So we have reduced the problem to picking among this list two groups that each sums to $126.5\pm0.5$; and further such that the products $u$ and $v$ of the corresponding integers in the first list are such that $p=2u+1$ and $q=2v+1$ are prime.

There are only $3^{12}$ ways to split $12$ integers into $3$ groups, and it's easy to prune this tree because we approximately know the sums ($126.5\pm0.5$ for the groups for $u$ and $v$, from which we deduce $15.246\pm1.001$ for the group for $k$). E.g. one of the two largest values must belong to $u$ and the other to $v$, and then the third largest must belong to one of these.

That hopefully yields $p$ and $q$, and then deciphering a message should be easy.